# How do I interact with the Amazon Product Advertising API in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, product, ads, amazon-product-advertising-api

I'm building a Rails web app and was wondering what is the best way to get a list of products that Amazon would return based on a search term?

For example, if I sent amazon the term "iphone", I'd get a list of iPhones back from Amazon.

Answer (score 5):

I've always used the amazon-ecs gem. Despite the name, it looks like it's still under active development (last updated August 27th, 2009).

http://github.com/jugend/amazon-ecs

Here is a blog post that might help you on your way:

http://www.pluitsolutions.com/projects/amazon-ecs

Answer (score 2):

So the Ruby/AWS library is the way to go.  There is a pretty good tutorial [here](http://www.jeffreyjason.com/2010/07/12/amazon-product-advertising-api-w-ruby/)

Pablo, ruby-aaws worked nearly out of the box for me.  I just had to setup a .amazonrc file with the configuration options like my amazon affiliate id and AWS public and secret keys.

Comment: ohh yea, and the maintainer seems to still be maintaining this API as of this spring (2010) at least.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ruby/AWS library (gem: ruby-aaws)](http://www.caliban.org/ruby/ruby-aws/) seems to do it. Not much in the way of examples, but with some code searches I'm sure you can turn up something.

Comment: Yes ruby-aws will do it.  It may take a bit of experimenting to get the exact results you want.  For example, there are various types of results and not all the types will return the price.

Comment: I've tried for a couple of hours wit ruby-aaws but amazon-ecs worked out of the box on the first try.

Comment: there are a number of examples in the gem code in the examples directory... at least a dozen, with comments

Answer (score 0):

Another pottential library to do this is [amazon-product-advertising-api](http://github.com/completelynovel/amazon-product-advertising-api), but I cannot say anything else about it as I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

I second Ruby/AWS. It has support for ListSearch and ListLookup. Amazon-ecs has comparatively less support for the API.